# Use RGB Customers Colors by Group in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have several series which I would like to animate with plotly R. After following the example here (https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/), I have the animation working. I figured out how to change the colors for the groups, however, I need specific colors for the groups (RGB custom colors).

I have two questions:

1. How do I assign RGB colors to groups in R Plotly...what am I missing here?
2. Is there an easier way to do this? I have several more "cities" than just two, and want to be able to dynamically assign the specific color. I was able to pull the colors in as a column in the data frame, and would like to be able to assign them that way...got it working for the regular colors, but need to get it for the RGB...

```
library(plotly)

# Helper function to create frames
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

# Pull in data and also create color columns
d <- 
  txhousing %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area")) %>%
  accumulate_by(~date) %>%
  mutate(regular_color = if_else(city == "Abilene", 'red', 'black'),
         RGB_color = if_else(city == "Abilene", 'rgb(229,18,18)', 'rgb(13,9,9)'))

# color vectors
reg_color_vector <- 
  d %>%
  arrange(city) %>%
  select(regular_color) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pull()
RGB_color_vector <- 
  d %>%
  arrange(city) %>%
  select(RGB_color) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pull()

p <- d %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~date, 
    y = ~median,
    split = ~city,
    frame = ~frame, 
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines', 
    line = list(simplyfy = F),
    color = ~city,
    # colors = c('red', 'black')
    colors = c('rgb(229, 18, 18)', 'rgb(13, 9, 9)')
    # colors = reg_color_vector
    # colors = RGB_color_vector
  ) %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = "Date",
      zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      title = "Median",
      zeroline = F
    )
  ) %>% 
  animation_opts(
    frame = 100, 
    transition = 0, 
    redraw = FALSE
  ) %>%
  animation_slider(
    hide = T
    ) %>%
  animation_button(
    x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
  )

p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgb()` is a function which outputs a hexadecimal value of the color you want. That is what you need to store. Remove the `'` and it should be fine. And you need to add `maxColorValue = 255` to the `rgb()` function.

```
d <- 
  txhousing %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area")) %>%
  accumulate_by(~date) %>%
  mutate(regular_color = if_else(city == "Abilene", 'red', 'black'),
         RGB_color = if_else(city == "Abilene", 
                             rgb(229, 18, 18, maxColorValue = 255), 
                             rgb(13, 9, 9, maxColorValue = 255)))
```

You can use in `plot_ly` than the `RGB_color_vector` to define the colors.

```
plot_ly(
  x = ~date, 
  y = ~median,
  split = ~city,
  frame = ~frame, 
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'lines', 
  line = list(simplyfy = F),
  color = ~city,
  colors = RGB_color_vector
)
```

Comment: Perfect. I had tried no quotes, but leaving out the `max` statement was throwing me off. Thanks!